# Calculate metrics from event data by id correlation

Tags: elastic-stack, metrics, influxdb

I have an application with a workflow that takes an object through a set of states, from `S_1 -> S_N`. I would like to log all of the state changes with the relevant data, like so:

> event: {id, timestamp, state }

Once I have gathered the data, I would like to process it to understand how long each step of the work is taking.

An example SQL query for this data looks like this (please excuse my sql skills if this query is poorly architected):

`select age(m2.event_time, m1.event_time)
from events m1 inner join events m2 
on m1.m_id = m2.m_id and m1.state = 'STATE_X' and m2.state = 'STATE_Y';`

This solution requires a relational database, which creates concerns for scalability and maintainability. We already have a time series database in production and I would ideally like to use that for this purpose. Is there a way to use something like ELK or Prometheus or InfluxDB to accomplish this task? Have I designed the solution incorrectly? Nothing I have found allows for queries of this nature.

Comment: I believe that unless you can change your event stream to smth like `event:{id,timestamp_old, timestamp_new,state_old,state_new}` or `event:{id,timestamp,state,duration}` it will be really hard to process in influxdb. With your current scheme approximate solution might be to group datapoints by time(interval) and count number of intervals with each state value.

Comment: Would that not still suffer from the same problem when trying to calculate state_1 -> state_5 if the workflow always moves from 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5?

Comment: You are right - neither data schema change nor interval counting approach can help to calculate arbitrary state transitions. I cannot comment anything on Prometheus or ELK? but good old SQL is your friend here. Consider using TimescaleDB or Clickhouse for your task.